# How can I add a popup (menu contribution) from an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, popup, swt, eclipse-rcp

I already have a popup working on the main Eclipse RCP application (3.X).
Now, I am trying to add a popup (menu contribution) to an Eclipse RCP plugin (it is linked to the application as a dependency). This plugin did not have the plugin.xml file that allows to add extensions, so I have created a new one. The popup configuration is as follows:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:table.popupmenu?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="copy"
           label="Copy"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        id="copy"
        name="Copy">
  </command>
</extension>
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
   <handler
         class="package.CopyHandler"
         commandId="copy">
   </handler>
</extension>
```

The handler class exists.
Then I have added to my "Table" class the following code to bind the menu (after creating the Table object):

```
IWorkbenchPartSite site = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
                                    .getActivePart().getSite();
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(this.table);
this.table.setMenu(menu);
site.registerContextMenu("table.popupmenu", menuManager, site.getSelectionProvider());
```

As I could not get it working I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html) (7.Tutorial: Commands and context menus), and works fine. I can not see the configuration i am missing.

If there is another good way to get a popup menu from a control (SWT) I would be glad to try that as well.

Comment: I think this is because you have `?after=additions` in the locationURI but the menu has no 'additions'  position. Try without that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `registerContextMenu` call sets the context menu for the part's selection provider - is your table the selection provider for the part?